# Invalid value for "path" parameter: open trying to read JSON files in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Im trying to read all the json files from a folder and try to loop through it for building the google_monitoring_alert_policy I get the json files from an folder named 'alt/*.json' but I get an error im not sure why its happening and if anything is missing in the code.
The main.tf looks like this

```
locals{
  json_file = fileset(path.module, "alt/*.json")

  alert_policies = {
    for files in local.json_file : files => jsondecode(templatefile(file(files), {
      tf_monitored_project = "test"

      tf_alert_name        = title("Alert for ${var.env}")
    }))
  }
}
```

The json files itself looks alright but Im not sure why this error happens

My error looks like this and the json file contents is part of the error

```
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│
│   on alert.tf line 16, in locals:
│   16:     for files in local.json_file : files => jsondecode(templatefile(file(files), {
│   17:       tf_monitored_project = "test"
│   18:       #local.monitored_resource_project[alt]
│   19:       tf_alert_name        = title("Alert for ${var.env}")
│   20:     }))
│
│ Invalid value for "path" parameter: open
│ {
│   "displayName": "${tf_alert_name}",
│   "documentation": {
│     "content": "Severity level: P1\n Resource: ",
│     "mimeType": "text\markdown"
│   },
│   "conditions": [
│     {
│       "displayName": "Cloud Composer Environment - Healthy",
│       "conditionThreshold": {
│         "filter": "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com\environment\healthy\" project=\"${tf_monitored_project}\"",
│         "aggregations": [
│           {
│             "alignmentPeriod": "600s",
│             "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_FRACTION_TRUE"
│           }
│         ],
│         "comparison": "COMPARISON_LT",
│         "duration": "0s",
│         "trigger": {
│           "count": 1
│         },
│         "thresholdValue": 0.5
│       }
│     },
│     {
│       "displayName": "Cloud Composer Environment - Database Health",
│       "conditionThreshold": {
│         "filter": "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com\environment\database_health\" project=\"${tf_monitored_project}\"",
│         "aggregations": [
│           {
│             "alignmentPeriod": "600s",
│             "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_FRACTION_TRUE"
│           }
│         ],
│         "comparison": "COMPARISON_LT",
│         "duration": "120s",
│         "trigger": {
│           "count": 1
│         },
│         "thresholdValue": 0.5
│       }
│     }
│   ],
│   "alertStrategy": {
│     "autoClose": "604800s",
│     "notificationPrompts": [
│       "OPENED"
│     ]
│   },
│   "combiner": "OR",
│   "enabled": true,
│   "notificationChannels": []
│ }: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect..
╵
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I have a similar requirement, could you please share how to pass these alert_policies read from json files to resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" to create alert policies?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112461/creating-gcp-monitoring-alert-policies-using-terraform-and-alert-policy-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` reads in the entire file content, while you need to specify file path in `templatefile`, not file content. So it should be:

```
for files in local.json_file : files => jsondecode(templatefile(files, {
```